# asp.net Invalid attempt to FieldCount when reader is closed error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465490/invalid-attempt-to-call-fieldcount-when-reader-is-closed)

im using asp.net with c#.
Im atempting to close the connection on the finally statement on aspx2.cs.

In  aspx1.cs:

```
private void BindDataGrids()
{
     try
     {
          DataGrid1.DataSource = instance.ShowDifferences(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString

["CrewId"]), DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["StartDate"]), DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["EndDate"]));
          DataGrid1.DataBind();
      }
 }
```

In  aspx2.cs:

```
 public static SqlDataReader ShowDifferences(int crewID, DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
 {
      Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
      string sqlCommand = "stored_procedure";
      DBCommandWrapper command = db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper(sqlCommand);
      try
      {
........code...........
         command.AddInParameter("@EndDate", DbType.Date, date2);
                IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(command);
         return (SqlDataReader)reader;
      }
      finally
      {
          command.Command.Connection.Close();
      }
```

When it reaches   DataGrid1.DataBind(); on aspx1.cs.

i get error:

```
"Invalid attempt to FieldCount when reader is closed error"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: where do you open the connection? Is the connection assigned to the sqlCommand? Do you close the connection somewhere else (e.g. by a using statement)?

Comment: in this line:   IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(command);    the connection opens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a reader that needs the connection to be open to be able to `Read`, but you close the connection before `ShowDifferences` exits. The reader is cursor that fetches data incrementally and has to be connected to the database for the whole process of reading. If you want to have an in-memory dataset (`DataTable`) disconnected from back-end database, consider using `Fill` method of `SqlDataAdapter`.

**Update:**

To "close the connection after the `DataGrid1.DataBind();`" move line

```
command.Command.Connection.Close();
```

to a separate method of `instance`'s class (e.g. `CloseConnection`) and call

```
instance.CloseConnection();
```

after `DataGrid1.DataBind();`. For this, of course, you need to change `DBCommandWrapper command` into `instance`'s class member.

Comment: you can find example of how SqlDataAdapter is used here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Comment: `adapter.SelectCommand = command.Command;`

Comment: `adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)command.Command;`

Comment: use `db.ExecuteDataSet(command)`

Comment: you do not the adapter if you use `db.ExecuteDataSet`

Comment: using the dataset is giving me lots of trouble. is there a way to keep the function as a sqldatareader and close the connection after the DataGrid1.DataBind(); ?

Comment: @pyram - Yes. See update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the connection when you use an `DbDataReader`, ExecuteReader does not open it automatically. Something like this:

```
using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
{
   conn.ConnectionString = connString;

   DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "...";

   conn.Open();
   DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   { ...
   }
}
```

Only when you use a `DataSet` you don't have to handle the connection. If you really open the connection in your ExecuteReader method, you have to keep it open as long as you keep the reader.