# GridView RowCreated: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error when the gridview is created with an empty dataset. What I am trying to do is populate a dropdown list in the EmptyDataTemplate. From reading other posts the error is caused by use SqlDataReader bind gridview after SqlConnection obejct closed. However, doesn't row created fire after the gridview row is populated?

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
    {
        string connectionString3 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("EOCEmpty");

        using (SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(connectionString3))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT GLAccountEOC, EOCDescription FROM Acct_GLAccount WHERE CostCenter = @CostCenter Order By EOCDescription", conn3);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@CostCenter", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd3.Parameters["@CostCenter"].Value = "3215";

            try
            {
                conn3.Open();
                SqlDataReader cmdreader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                ddl.DataSource = cmdreader3;
                ddl.DataValueField = "GLAccountEOC";
                ddl.DataTextField = "EOCDescription";
                ddl.DataBind();
                cmdreader3.Close();
            }

            finally
            {
                conn3.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well you are binding the reader then closing it. also you could check `HasRows` first to determine if you want to bind to the reader

Comment: @Nkosi In my gridview?, yes I am using HasRows to determine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem occur in these lines:

```
SqlDataReader cmdreader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
ddl.DataSource = cmdreader3;
```

As you should know, [`ExecuteReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader) method builds `SqlDataReader` instance (which is forward-only stream), and the connection seem to be closed when trying to access the reader. Consider using [`SqlDataReader.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to open the reader and advances to first record, or load the contents into in-memory `DataSet`/`DataTable` and use it as GridView's data source instead.

Here is an example to load `SqlDataReader` contents inside `DataTable`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(connectionString3))
{
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT GLAccountEOC, EOCDescription FROM Acct_GLAccount WHERE CostCenter = @CostCenter Order By EOCDescription", conn3);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@CostCenter", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd3.Parameters["@CostCenter"].Value = "3215";

    try
    {
        conn3.Open();
        SqlDataReader cmdreader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        if (cmdreader3.HasRows)
        {
            dt.Load(cmdreader3);
            ddl.DataSource = dt; // use DataTable instead of SqlDataReader
            ddl.DataValueField = "GLAccountEOC";
            ddl.DataTextField = "EOCDescription";
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
        cmdreader3.Close();
    }

    finally
    {
        conn3.Close();
    }
}
```

If the problem still persists, use [`RowDataBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2) event handler instead of [`RowCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated?view=netframework-4.7.2) to populate dropdownlist value (see [difference between RowCreated & RowDataBound event](https://forums.asp.net/t/996312.aspx?RowDataBound%20VS%20RowCreated)).

Similar issue:

[asp.net Invalid attempt to FieldCount when reader is closed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728240/asp-net-invalid-attempt-to-fieldcount-when-reader-is-closed-error)

Comment: Thank you I used RowDataBound instead of RowCreated and it worked.