# Data reader get closed while passing to a method

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to pass data reader to a method but getting error like below :

> Invalid attempt to call fieldcount when reader is closed.

**Code** :

```
public class ImportService
{
    public IDataReader Reader { get; set; }
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
       string[] Tables = { "Table1", "Table2"};
       foreach (var table in Tables)
       {
          try
           {
                var msSql = new MsSql(table,conn);
                Reader = msSql.Reader;
                msSql.Reader.Close();
                DumpData(conn, Reader);
                Reader.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                 //catch exception here
                 Reader.Close();//in case of error while dumping data close the reader.
           }
       }

       conn.close();
   }

   private void DumpData(SqlConnection conn, IDataReader reader) //Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed
   {
   }
}

public class MsSql
{
     public IDataReader Reader { get; set; }
     public MsSql(string table, SqlConnection Conn)
     {
             GetData(table,Conn);
     }
     private void GetData(string table, SqlConnection Conn)
     {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
     }
}
```

I am successfully getting data in my global object Reader but when I pass it to my dumpdata method I get an error.

I have already checked the below questions, but they couldn't help me with my current scenario :

- [Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465490/invalid-attempt-to-call-fieldcount-when-reader-is-closed)
- [asp.net Invalid attempt to FieldCount when reader is closed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728240/asp-net-invalid-attempt-to-fieldcount-when-reader-is-closed-error)

**Update**: When I pass `msSql.Reader` to Dumpdata then everything works fine like below:

```
DumpData(conn, msSql.Reader);
```

Comment: Well you're closing the `SqlCommand` in `GetData`... how did you expect to be able to read data from the closed command?

Comment: @JonSkeet:But i am getting records successfully in my msSql.Reader and when i pass msSql.Reader to DumpData method it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is this:

1. Retrieving the Reader `Reader = msSql.Reader;`
2. Closing the self-same Reader `msSql.Reader.Close();`
3. Attempting to read data from the, now closed, Reader: `DumpData(conn, Reader)`

So you are trying to read from a closed reader (that's presumably what `DumpData()` does - and get a corresponding message.

I think you are labouring under the mis-apprehension that by assigning the same object to another variable you are creating another object. This is not so. You are merely referencing it from more than one point.

So: `msSql.Reader` and the local `Reader` both refer to the same object.

Comment: Ok i understand now and you are right but the reason behind doing this is because if i get any in dumpmethod then how i will close reader of mssql class then?

Comment: you should use a `using` statement around your reader code - that will cause the Reader to be disposed and therefore closed regardless of exceptions etc.

Comment: All right.Thank you so much for the help and please keep helping like this :)